# What is syntax for creating a class in C# that would be equal to a Module in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I do almost all of my programming in VB.net (all flavors). I am now been assigned a task to make a new routine in an existing C# application. What I want to be able to do is pass a string variable to a class where I can figure out device type of a symbol handheld and figure out where an executable resides on device.
I am trying to keep the class to contain changes we make going forward in one place.

so a brief description is on a screen there will be a button. on that button click I want pass the text of the button to a (what would be a module in VB) a class and depending on text being passed and device type call a separate executable that lives on the device.

Everything I have tried so far has thrown errors.
On my button click i have

```
    String Reponse =   clsCallAction("Activity");
```

but that gets a message that clsCallAction is a type but is used like a variable.

here is the smaple of clsCallaction

```
    internal static partial class clsCallAction
     {
public static object GetPath(object lAppName)
{
    string resp = "";
    if (lAppName.Equals("Activity"))

    {
        resp = @"\application\activity.exe";
    }

    return resp;
}
   }
```

If I put new in front of the clsCallAction("Activity") on button click I get a
cannot create instance of the static class 'clsCalACtion'

appreciate any pointers. very new at C#

Comment: `clsCallAction.GetPath("Activity")`? Why are you using `object`s though? The `GetPath` method should probably be `public static string GetPath(string lAppName)`. Also, I can't think of anything similar to `clsCallAction("Activity")` that is possible in VB. How would you do that with a VB Module?

Comment: I don't see where your confusion comes from. If in VB `clsCallAction` was a module, that would also be `clsCallAction.GetPath`.

Comment: Moreover, you should drop the `cls` prefix in both your VB and C# code. For more about naming conventions, please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) and [here](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md).

Comment: All good comments. I am struggling on setting up the class from scratch. As for the comment of why I am using objects I don't want to. I just want to pass string to class and for it to return a path to executable

Comment: The only difference between a C# static class and a VB module is that members of the former must be qualified with the type name while the latter don't have to be. That's no great mystery though, because it's exactly the same as a `Shared` member of a VB class. Have you ever called a method like `File.ReadAllText`? If so, you already know how to call a method of a `static` class so why are you trying to make this harder than it is?

Comment: *"I just want to pass string to class and for it to return a path to executable"*. Then do that. If the method returns a `string`, why declare the return type as `object`? It should be obvious that you declare it as `string`.

Comment: System.Object Equals method checks to see if the 2 objects point to the same memory location. Obviously that will be false in your example.

Answer (score 1):

It would look something like this:

```
public static class CallAction
{
  public static object GetPath(object lAppName)
  {
    string resp = "";
    if (lAppName.Equals("Activity"))
    {
        resp = @"\application\activity.exe";
    }

    return resp;
  }
}
```

And would be used like this:

```
String Reponse =   CallAction.GetPath("Activity");
```

- Don't prefix classes with `cls`
- Avoid using `object` if possible - it just makes everything harder work than it needs to be.. Kinda like calling everything "thing" - ("Put the thing in the thing and open the thing" is harder to understand than "put the key in the lock and open the door")